# Make python repeat a string until Yes or yes is inputted

Tags: python, while-loop

Yes I know that there is already a post covering this, but when I read it, it didn't help so please don't mark this as a duplicate.

I want to write a program that asks the user if they want advice and if they input "No" or "no" I want it to repeat the question and if they input "Yes" or "yes" I want it to print the advice. I want it to include a while loop

I have tried to write it myself but I can't get it to work correctly.

Anyone know?

Code from the comment for 3.4 -

```
def doQuestion(question, advice):
reply = ("no")

while reply  == "no":


print (question)





reply = input("Do you need some advice? ").lower()





if (reply == "yes"):


print ("Always listen to your IT teachers") 



 doQuestion("Do you want some advice?","Always listen to your IT teachers")
```

Comment: Help us help you - please share your current efforts.

Comment: Remember when using conditionals like the while, you must indent so the code knows what lines are included in the conditional block.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The following will keep on checking up on the user to see whether or not they need advice regarding a question:

```
def doTheyNeedAdvice(advice):
    while raw_input("Do you need advice? ").lower() == "no":
        pass
    print (advice)

print "How old am I?"

doTheyNeedAdvice("I am old enough")
```

Comment: Hi, thanks for your answer. It really helped although there is just one more problem. When the program starts, the question is printed twice. I've copied the code for python 3.4 and changed it to what I need.                                                               def doQuestion(question, advice):
    reply = ("no")
    while reply  == "no":
        print (question)
        reply = input("Do you need some advice? ").lower()
    if (reply == "yes"):
        print ("Always listen to your IT teachers") 

doQuestion("Do you want some advice?","Always listen to your IT teachers")

Comment: The program asks you if you need advice and then asks you the question.  Do you mean you want a program to just ask if you need advice on a loop?  Or do you want it to only ask the question once?

Comment: yeah then if the user wants advice, it says the advice, but if they input no, it loops the question until they say yes. I'm not good at python so I don't know if that makes sence.