# variables are updating to print accurate scores

Tags: python

i have to write a code that generates a number for 2 players, then who ever has the biggest points between the 2 players gets a point. First player to 10 points wins and the program should print who wins and also tally up the numbers generated for total points earned. i cannot get the variables to update. also the program runs too quickly, im not sure how to get it to where the user has to push enter to start a new game.

ive tried using `def main():` along with global variables and `return`, non of which are working.

```
import random

player_one =input("Enter player 1's name: ").title()
player_two =input("Enter player 2's name: ").title()

total_score1 = 0
total_score2 = 0


for x in range(1,13):
        player_1 = random.randint(1, 13)
        player_2 = random.randint(1, 13)

        if player_1 > player_2:
            total_score1 = total_score1 + 1



        else:
            player_1 < player_2
            total_score2 = total_score2 + 1

            print(player_one,'\t',player_1,'\t',player_two,'\t',player_2)
        if player_1 == player_2:
            print("Both numbers were equal")


if total_score1 > total_score2:
        print(player_one, "Wins, total points:",total_score1)
else:
        print(player_two, "Wins, total points:", total_score2)
```

expected ouput:

```
Payer 1 wins, total points:
```

variable not updating

Comment: use if, elif, else. Also you code is not correct. inside the else, you just have player_1 < player_2, which is not correct if you do not have if or else around it

Comment: Read https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/ for tips on debugging your code.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. Please follow the posting guidelines in the help documentation, as suggested when you created this account. [On topic](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic), [how to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), and ... [the perfect question](https://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2010/08/29/writing-the-perfect-question/) apply here. StackOverflow is not a design, coding, research, or tutorial resource.  You've asked multiple questions, you provide no output, and your desired output doesn't jibe with the code you wrote.

Comment: I recommend that you adopt incremental programming: get one aspect of your program working before you go on to the next.  I expect that you have a focus problem, because you tried to write the entire program at once, and you're now trying to debug several problems at the same time.  For instance, your outer loop runs 12 iterations, ignoring the 10-point winning criterion; your output gives the player's name, rather than the "Payer 1" [sic] you say you want.  Your method of resolving each round is faulty, as you've noted.  Each of these items is readily solved in isolation.

Comment: For instance, repeating the game is a commonly asked question: see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42884392/make-python-repeat-a-string-until-yes-or-yes-is-inputted). Basic loop control, (`for` versus `while`) is available in many tutorials.  Writing an `if-elif-else` for greater, equal, less is also in many tutorials.  Output control and formatting are a separate set of references, as well.

Comment: thank you everyone for your answers, im only a beginner coder so im still new to this

Answer (score 0):

This works! I altered the if else to include and elif, makes the code more succinct.

EDIT: changed for for while to sotp game at 10 points, and slowed down with sleep.

```
import random
import time

player_one ='j'
player_two ='t'

total_score1 = 0
total_score2 = 0


while total_score1 < 10 and total_score2 < 10:
    player_1 = random.randint(1, 13)
    player_2 = random.randint(1, 13)

    if player_1 > player_2:
        total_score1 = total_score1 + 1
        print(player_one,'\t',player_1)
        time.sleep(1)


    elif player_1 < player_2:
        total_score2 = total_score2 + 1
        print(player_two,'\t',player_2)
        time.sleep(1)

    else: 
        print("Both numbers were equal")
        time.sleep(1)


if total_score1 > total_score2:
        print(player_one, "Wins, total points:",total_score1)
else:
        print(player_two, "Wins, total points:", total_score2)
```

Output:

```
('j', '\t', 12)
('j', '\t', 10)
('t', '\t', 13)
('t', '\t', 13)
('j', '\t', 10)
('t', '\t', 8)
('t', '\t', 5)
('j', '\t', 8)
('j', '\t', 8)
Both numbers were equal
Both numbers were equal
('j', '\t', 13)
('t', '\t', 4)
('t', '\t', 3)
('j', '\t', 13)
('j', '\t', 13)
('t', '\t', 13)
('t', '\t', 9)
('j', '\t', 12)
('t', '\t', 9)
('t', '\t', 12)
('t', 'Wins, total points:', 10)
```

Comment: thank you for your help, how do i get the total_score variable to update and add up all the generated numbers for that player?

Comment: running your original code updated the scores. What are you using? jupyter, spyder, etc?

Comment: im using IDLE, running 3.6

Comment: hm, it runs fine on spyder, try a different IDE or restarting. Also, i further edited the code to accommodate what you wanted.